# Ignore spaces in regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex

```
(?i)(\bl\b|\bline\b)(\s*)(555)
```

and I am trying to match the string `Line555`. The expression works for matching `line 555` or `Line 555`, however, if i remove the space between the two, it no longer works. Can anyone explain why?

Thank you in advance

Comment: the last \b is not optional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) before `\s` pattern, there is no word boundary between `e` and `5` in `Line555`.  Just to remind of what positions are matched with a word boundary:

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

So, use

```
(?i)\b(l(?:ine)?)(\s*)(555)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rWW5WP/1). Remove capturing groups if you are not interested in those submatches.

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `(l(?:ine)?)` - Group 1: `l` and then an optional `ine` substring
- `(\s*)` - Group 2: 0+ whitespaces
- `(555)` - Group 3: `555` substring.